# Adding Each Column in 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble adding each columns in my 2D array. It seems as if my code is not adding the columns correctly, thus I cannot calculate the correct averages. I was able to add and get the average of each of my rows, but I do not know about the columns. There must be a little mistake I am making in my code, please help me find it.

P.S. My array is int book [3][4] and the students are each column so I have 4 students in total as so I do columns.

```
public void AverageStudent(int[][] book) //columns
{
     double average1 = 0;
     double sum1 = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < book[0].length; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < book.length; k++)
            {
                sum1 += book[i][k];
                average1 = sum1 / book.length;
                System.out.println("The average of student " + (k+1) + " is " + average1);
                sum1 = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

This is the Output the code above gives.

> 1 2   3   4
>   1   2   3   4
>   1   2   3   4
>   The average of test 1 is 2.5
>   The average of test 2 is 2.5
>   The average of test 3 is 2.5
>   The average of student 1 is 0.3333333333333333
>   The average of student 2 is 0.6666666666666666
>   The average of student 3 is 1.0
>   The average of student 4 is 1.3333333333333333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic mistake in this statement : `sum1 += book[i][k];`

it should be `book[k][i]` because `i` is iterating on columns and `k` is iterating on rows.

this should work for student average by each column:

```
       public void AverageStudent(int[][] book) //columns
       {
           double average1,sum1;

          for (int i = 0; i < book[0].length; i++)
          {     sum1 = 0;
                average1 = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < book.length; k++)
            {
                sum1 += book[k][i];               
            }
               average1 = sum1 / book.length;
               System.out.println("The average of student " + (i+1) + " is " + average1);
          }
       }
```

Comment: However, the code above only prints out "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3" @MohammadOghil

Comment: But k is underlined in red now so wouldn't I have to move " System.out.println("The average of student " + (k+1) + " is " + average1);" into the second for loop? @MohammadOghli

Comment: you have logic mistake in : sum1 += book[i][k]

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: it should be book[k][i] because i is iterating on columns and k is iterating on rows.

Comment: @AmandaB.  see this online example by me:
https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/JLPUXWGNYT

Comment: This is extacly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare `average1` and `sum1` inside of the first `for` loop. Currently, they keep getting reset after each element, it should ideally happen after each row. Below code works fine.

```
public void AverageStudent(int[][] book) {
    for (int i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
        double average1 = 0;
        double sum1 = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < book[i].length; k++) {
            sum1 += book[i][k];
        }
        average1 = sum1 / book[i].length;
        System.out.println("The average of student " + (i + 1) + " is " + average1);
        sum1 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: My array is int book [3][4] and the students are each column so I have 4 students in total as so I do columns. However, the code above only prints out 3 students and it does not calculate the correct averages. @DarshanMehta